# Control speed of particles on a Curve Guide?

Tags: particles, bezier-curves

I am trying to control the speed of the particles that I have set up with a Curve guide. I have changed the settings for Drag and Damp along with Timestep and none of these affect the speed. Also I have tried every setting in the Velocity drop down under particle systems and also no luck.

What else could I try to slow down these particles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For slower particle speed change the lifetime of the particle to a larger value.

[image]

Click on image to see original larger version.

You may also need to make other artistic adjustments.

Comment: You are awesome! that was it! Never would of guessed that.

Comment: No.  You are awesome.  I heard it all over the internet.